# R, double integral with functional boundaries

Tags: r, integral, boundary

Is there an R function that handles double integrals where the region of the inner integration is a function of the outer variable? That is to say, while f(x) is integrated from -5 to 5, g(y) is integrated over 0 to h(x).

Thanks,
JD

Answer (score 2):

See the function `integral2` in the *pracma* package which does exactly what you are asking for. Here is one of the examples from the help page:

```
##  Compute the volume of a sphere
f <- function(x, y) sqrt(1 -x^2 - y^2)
xmin <- 0; xmax <- 1
ymin <- 0; ymax <- function(x) sqrt(1 - x^2)
I <- integral2(f, xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
I$Q                             # 0.5236076 - pi/6 => 8.800354e-06
```

where one of the limits, `ymax`, is a function while the other limits are constants, but could also be functions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `adaptIntegrate` function from the `cubature` library.  I will assume for the sake of an example that your function is `f(x, y) = x + y`:

```
library(cubature)
fun <- function(x) x[1] + x[2]
adaptIntegrate(fun, c(0, 10), c(-5, 5), tol=1e-8)
```

This integrates over `y` from 0 to 10, then over `x` from -5 to 5.

Note that `adaptIntegrate` does **not** appear to accept a function as integral bounds.  So if you want to the outer integral to go from 0 to `h(x)` you will probably have to write your own quadrature (not a hard thing to do).